# iphone objective-c interesting problem with accessory and setEditing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, warnings, accessory

In my DetailViewController i have the code

**UPDATED x2**

This is my **setEditing**

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    [tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];  //this line was added to force editing Mode
....
```

In my detailViewController I want to send tableView the 'magic/whatever it is' to register 'editing mode' to change the accessory, but I dont want to bring up the delete buttons. Previously I didnt have the line  `[tableView setEditing:editing animated:YES];`, and so I only want it to bring up the accessory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely fix this.

When you create the table view cell (in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`), set the `accessoryType` property to `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone` and the `editingAccessoryType` property to `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator`.

You do this instead of implementing the deprecated `tableView:accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:` method.

Comment: can someone have another look now? I can get cell.accessoryType = ... to work, but not the cell.editingAccessoryType!

Comment: You don't need to implement `setEditing:animated:`, but you DO need to tell the table view to go into editing mode (somewhere else) when appropriate (or use the standard edit button which does this for you).